# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-hosted

I am working of another older project of mine as reference and within this blazor compononent I get this error ->

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[List`1](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[List`1](String value)
   at FinnivoLicenseManagement.Client.Pages.LandingPage.LoadData()
   at FinnivoLicenseManagement.Client.Pages.LandingPage.OnInitializedAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

This happens as soon as the page loads up. The API is not even called when this happens. After the error appears the API call starts.  Tested the api within the page and it is working fine.

Here is my component code->

```
@page "/landing"
@using FinnivoLicenseManagement.Shared
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@layout NoMenuLayout
@inject NavigationManager UriHelper
@inject HttpClient _httpClient

@if (IsLoading)
{
<div class="spinner-border" role="status" justify-content:center; position:center;">
    @*<span class="sr-only"/>*@
</div>
}
else{
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Module Usage</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Module</th>
                <th>Number of Users</th>
                <th>Manage</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var module in moduleDetailsList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@module.ModuleName</td>
                    <td>
                        @module.NumberOfUsers
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => NavigateToEdit(module.Id))">Manage Module Licenses</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
}



@code {
    private bool IsLoading { get; set; }
    List<ModuleDetails> moduleDetailsList = new List<ModuleDetails>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        await LoadData();
        IsLoading = false;
    }

    protected async Task LoadData()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/ModuleDetails/GetModuleDetails");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            moduleDetailsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModuleDetails>>(jsonResult);

        }
        moduleDetailsList?.ToList();
    }

    private void NavigateToEdit(int moduleId)
    {
        UriHelper.NavigateTo($"/managemodule/{moduleId}");
    }
}
```

Is there anything i am missing or doing wrong? My reference project works 100%.

Tried a different way of parsing the data. Needs to populate the list moduleDetailsList.

Any advice on what to try will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried logging `jsonResult` or looking at it in a debugger? My guess is that it's HTML or XML, not JSON...

Comment: I tried it but this happens as soon as the page is loaded. The api is not even called at that moment.

Comment: Well the API *has* been called if it's failing in `DeserializeObject`. You could comment out that call for now...

Comment: Are you sure that a valid response (json format) was received by the server (verify with devtools of the browser - F12)? 
Try to use `GetFromJsonAsync<TResult>(path)`, it set the header with accepted content type to json and deserialize the result to the expected type.

Comment: So, there's the method you use to deserialize the received json that tells you it's "not a valid json". You ask us why, but you don't show us the json that returns from the API call. This doesn't make much sense. We can only guess and I would say that someone has given you an important tip. Now if you want a more precise answer you should show us the value of the string present in the content. Please then tell us what value the variable _jsonResuslt_ has.

Comment: This is what I get when using PostMan -> [{"id":2,"moduleName":"Administration","numberOfUsers":10},{"id":3,"moduleName":"Consolidation","numberOfUsers":15},{"id":4,"moduleName":"Enterprise","numberOfUsers":7},{"id":5,"moduleName":"Export","numberOfUsers":5},{"id":6,"moduleName":"Super User","numberOfUsers":1},{"id":7,"moduleName":"Analytics","numberOfUsers":12},{"id":8,"moduleName":"Import","numberOfUsers":9},{"id":9,"moduleName":"Publisher","numberOfUsers":20},{"id":10,"moduleName":"Xtra Reports","numberOfUsers":18},{"id":11,"moduleName":"XBRL","numberOfUsers":1}]

Comment: The opening div `<div class="spinner-border" role="status" justify-content:center; position:center;">` seems to be malformed. I'm assuming `justify-content:center; position:center;"` should actually be `style="justify-content:center; position:center;"`